# Is there any possible way of including if else condiotion in struct?

Tags: c++, c

I am new in this and I am not sure if I am doing the right thing or not. I want to do an if else statement inside the structure but I get an error.
maybe something like this

```
menuItem_t messageCentre[] = {

    if (drainUpdate == true){
    {"New Message Arrived", {MENUACTION_GOTOCUSTOM, &messageDrainCustomWithData}},
    else{
    {"No Message", {MENUACTION_GOTOCUSTOM, &messageCentreCustomWithData}},
    }

};
```

I have tried this also

```
#ifdef drainUpdate
    {"New Message Arrived", {MENUACTION_GOTOCUSTOM, &messageDrainCustomWithData}},
    #else
    {"No Message", {MENUACTION_GOTOCUSTOM, &messageCentreCustomWithData}},
#endif
```

but no luck. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just initialize `messageCentre` inside `if (drainUpdate == true) {`?

Comment: "Something like this" and the idea of code within a C struct make this question very unclear to me. Consider deleting the C tag.

Comment: You could indicate if `drainUpdate` is known at compilation time or not

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to do, but from what little I gathered, I think you may just want to initialize the struct however and then set the conditional fields afterwards in a n if statement

Comment: @DimChtz Then it wouldn't be available outside of `if` scope.

Comment: Toss the `{"New Message Arrived", {MENUACTION_GOTOCUSTOM, &messageDrainCustomWithData}}` etc part into a temporary struct variable which you init before the struct. Then pass that temp variable to the initializer list. Keep it simple.

Comment: I'd suggest reopening. This is a reasonable beginners question, and rustyx has the essence of the answer (`?:` expression). Fundamentally, the syntax problem is that `if` in C++ is a statement. In other languages like Python, it can also be used as an expression, but C++ inherited the `?:` expression for that purpose.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. You need to chose one and provide some [mre] in your question. If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c foo.c` to compile the C file `foo.c`, and use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c bar.cc` to compile the C++ file `bar.cc`. Then use the GDB debugger

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I said initialize inside if, not declare :)

Comment: I'm sorry, voting to close again. The context in which the question is asked is very unclear. Is this inside a function or at global scope? Is this C or C++? Is the structure shared? Is `menuItem_t` an aggregate type? Please read [ask] and edit a [mcve] into the question.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is a statement, but what you need is an expression. Luckily, there's an "if-like" expression, called `?:` (also known as ternary expression, because it has three subexpressions).

```
menuItem_t messageCentre[] =     
    { 
          drainUpdate ? "New Message Arrived" : "No Message",
          {
               MENUACTION_GOTOCUSTOM, 
               drainUpdate ? &messageDrainCustomWithData : &messageCentreCustomWithData
          }
    };
```